# removeAllView() and removeAllViewsInLayout() is not removing

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, removeall

Thanks in advance and here is my problem. I have a database and i have to show its content whenever the "SHOW DATA" button is clicked (on the same activity (layout)). so when the user clicks again that button i want to remove the views in the layout so that the content of the database is not shown twice. I've have used removeAllView() and removeAllViewsInLayout() but it seems it's not working (for sure i'm not using correctly this method).

Here is the java code :

```
public void onClickShowData(){

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardViewContainer);

    ll.removeAllViews();


    showAll.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData();

                    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        showData("Error", "Nothing found");
                        return;
                    }


                    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.cardViewContainer);
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();

                    LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(context);
                    ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    ll2.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                    TextView tv = new TextView(context);

                    CardView cv = new CardView(context);

                    cv.setId(R.id.cardView);

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                        tmp.append("name : " + cursor.getString(0) + "\n" +
                                "calory : " + cursor.getString(1) + "\n" +
                                "protein : " + cursor.getString(2) + "\n" +
                                "lipid : " + cursor.getString(3) + "\n" +
                                "clucid: " + cursor.getString(4));
                        ll.addView(cv);
                        cv.addView(ll2);
                        tv.setText(tmp.toString());
                        ll2.addView(tv);
                    }




                }
            }
    );
}
```

and this is the layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_database"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="gafood.mobiledeviceproject.arianchitgar.foodmakerwithga.databaseActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewLL">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                android:hint="Food name"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/Calory"
                android:hint="Calory"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Calory"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Calory"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Calory"
                android:id="@+id/protein"
                android:hint="Protein" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/protein"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/lipid"
                android:hint="Lipid" />

            <Button
                android:text="Add food"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lipid"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:id="@+id/addFood" />

            <Button
                android:text="Update"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addFood"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/updateFood" />

            <Button
                android:text="Delete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/updateFood"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:id="@+id/delete" />

            <Button
                android:text="Food DB"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addFood"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/showAll" />

            <Button
                android:text="search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/updateFood"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/updateFood"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/updateFood"
                android:id="@+id/search" />

            <Button
                android:text="Advanced"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/delete"
                android:id="@+id/advancedSearch" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewContainer"></LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>


enter code here
```

[When the app starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcNA9.png)
[When i click 3 times on show DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKGq7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardViewContainer);
```

This line from inside onClickShowData() method and, add

```
LinearLayout ll;
```

To the top of your activity class.
then in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method add,

```
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardViewContainer);
```

In your current code, you are adding views to an ll and calling ll.removeAllViews() in a different object.

the final code should be something like,

```
public class YourActivityName extends Activity {
LinearLayout ll;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardViewContainer);
        // .... other code //
}

public void onClickShowData(){
    ll.removeAllViews();
    showAll.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllData();

                    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        showData("Error", "Nothing found");
                        return;
                    }


                    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();


                    Context context = getApplicationContext();

                    LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(context);
                    ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    ll2.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                    TextView tv = new TextView(context);

                    CardView cv = new CardView(context);

                    cv.setId(R.id.cardView);

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                        tmp.append("name : " + cursor.getString(0) + "\n" +
                                "calory : " + cursor.getString(1) + "\n" +
                                "protein : " + cursor.getString(2) + "\n" +
                                "lipid : " + cursor.getString(3) + "\n" +
                                "clucid: " + cursor.getString(4));
                        ll.addView(cv);
                        cv.addView(ll2);
                        tv.setText(tmp.toString());
                        ll2.addView(tv);
                    }

                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `onClick()` listener with `showAll.setOnClickListener` but the code that gets executed does not include `ll.removeAllViews()`. Change your click listener to something like the following to remove views when the button is clicked.

```
showAll.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardViewContainer);
    ll.removeAllViews();

...etc.
```